# Is it possible to add a button on Excel sheet using Office Js Api?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I am building an Excel Addin using Office JS API. I have found a workaround to dynamically generate drop-down lists and now I am wondering whether I can add a Button on excel sheet using Excel JS API

Comment: Do you mean a custom button on the Office ribbon? That can only be done with the add-in's manifest. There's no way at present to do it programmatically at runtime.

Comment: no, I mean to add a button on a cell or on a range of cells of an Excel Sheet. I know that on the Ribbon, buttons are entered through manifest explicitly.

Comment: There is no way to add a button to the spreadsheet itself with the Excel JavaScript Library.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot Rick. I had seen this answer in a previous post in 2016, so I just wanted to make sure it is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that currently there is no way to add a button to the spreadsheet itself with the Excel JavaScript Library.

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot add a button through the Exel Javascript Library, you can format a cell to look like a button and have it execute your javascript code when clicked.  See a post I wrote on this: [Excel Office.js -add button on Workbook_Open() envent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963688/excel-office-js-add-button-on-workbook-open-envent/70548681#70548681)